# Is lead iodide a strong electrolyte?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, solubility, ions, ionic-compounds

So, lead iodide is insoluble. I see conflicting answers online. Some say it's a weak electrolyte because it is insoluble, others say it is a strong electrolyte because it is an ionic compound and any small amount that dissolves does so in the form of ions.

Which one is the correct answer?

Comment: Solubility and being strong/weak electrolyte are 2 independent properties.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Poutnik. So, is it a strong or weak electrolyte then?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_electrolyte

Comment: From that Wikipedia article: 

Strong acids, strong bases and soluble ionic salts that are not weak acids or weak bases are strong electrolytes.

It says soluble ionic salts..lead iodide is insoluble. I did my research, I just asked because I couldn't find a definitive answer!

Comment: *A strong electrolyte is a solution/solute that completely, or almost completely, ionizes or dissociates in a solution.* It says nothing about solubility.

Comment: Actually, since it mentions that **soluble** ionic salts are strong electrolytes it does refer to solubility.

Comment: Saying European cars are good does not say that American cars are not good. // Insoluble salts are not usually considered as electrolytes at all, but if they are, they usually are strong electrolytes. In fact, I cannot remember a case that would not be. It would mean both ions would hydrolyze to neutral weak acid and base.

Comment: First it has to be strongly soluble. I would argue it isn't (in water).

Comment: The definition uses the word "almost".  Educational treatments of insoluble salts assume ions are formed when we think they are tempered by different degrees of solvation or even complexation. Take the alkaline earth hydroxides barium is considered strong because it is soluble, no one cares about strontium, calcium is considered insoluble but strong because lime is used to dissolve bodies in murder mysteries, and we eat milk of magnesia to relieve dyspepsia. Teachers must stop making such definite statements without proof or data or at least rationales. Help the students think not memorize.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Then being strong/weak electrolyte would be an attribute of a solution, not of a compound.  Consider 1 mM PbI2 vs 1 mM H2SO4 vs 1 M H2SO4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Lead(II) iodide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead(II)_iodide) is sparingly soluble in water at room temperature $(\pu{0.76 g/L}$ at $\pu{20 °C})$ and a bit more soluble in hot water $(\pu{4.1 g/L}$ at $\pu{100 °C}).$ In solution, all of the lead iodide is dissociated into ions. At high concentrations of iodide, the lead ions form two complexes, $\ce{PbI3-}$ and $\ce{PbI4^2-}$ [[1](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01848a010)]:

> The increase of solubility of lead iodide caused by the presence of iodide ion in concentration greater than 0.1 molal may be explained by the formation of the complex ions $\ce{PbI3-}$ and $\ce{PbI4^=}.$

In any case, all of the dissolved lead iodide is present as ions (there is no neutral $\ce{PbI2(aq)}$ species), so it is a strong electrolyte. This is different from weak electrolytes such as, say, acetic acid, where there is a neutral species $\ce{CH3COOH(aq)}$ in solution which dissociates into the charged $\ce{CH3COO-(aq)}$ and $\ce{H+(aq)}$.

As an aside, the difference in color (colorless in solution, yellow as a solid) and the temperature-dependence of the solubility leads to a beautiful effect that has been called toxic golden rain, see e.g. video [YouTube — Golden Rain - Growing crystals of lead iodide. Chemical reaction](https://youtu.be/TRq9hnOGvaE?t=74).

#### Reference

1. Lanford, O. E.; Kiehl, S. J. The Solubility of Lead Iodide in Solutions of Potassium Iodide-Complex Lead Iodide Ions. *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1941**, 63 (3), 667–669. DOI: [10.1021/ja01848a010](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01848a010).

Comment: A devil advocate may object how there can be $\ce{Pb^2+(aq)}$, $\ce{[PbI3]-(aq)}$ and $\ce{[PbI4]^2-(aq)}$ without $\ce{[PbI2](aq)}$.

Comment: @Poutnik You may ponder the opposite: Why do the complex ions not precipitate with a counter ion? The cite paper mentions double salts such as $\ce{RI.PbI2.H2O}$, and [methylammonium lead iodide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methylammonium_lead_halide) is an example.